# Heatmap.2 Rowv=F not working to avoid reordering

Tags: r, rows, heatmap, gplots

I have a given matrix with a given order "filtered2" I am using from gplots to construct a heatmap that should have the same order of rows found in the matrix, however it is still reordering even using Rowv=FALSE, this is the command that I am using it:

```
heatmap.2(filtered2,trace="none",density.info="none",
          col=redgreen,dendrogram="none", Rowv=F,Colv=F)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the problem was that the heatmap was long and the program coudln't display all the row labels!!